# Summing like results in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to list the total number of people who speak a language, so far I have come up with:

```
SELECT 
  language.name, 
  (country.population * (language.percentage / 100)) 
FROM 
 language, 
 country
ORDER BY name;
```

And this returns every language and the number who speak it, but it does it for each country that has a population who speaks that language, for instance:

```
"Afghan Persian";1624568.00000000000000000000
"Afghan Persian";5269297.00000000000000000000
"Afghan Persian";1052017.50000000000000000000
```

What can I do to make only one row for each language with the sum of the total world population who speaks it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need a join.  A simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Then table aliases make the query easier to follow.  And, you want an aggregation query . . . `GROUP BY` and `SUM()`:

```
SELECT l.name, 
       SUM(c.population * (l.percentage / 100)) 
FROM language l JOIN
     country c
     ON l.countryId = c.countryId -- Or whatever the proper JOIN condition is
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY name;
```

Comment: thank you, I was over thinking it I was able to adapt that into a working solution.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use an aggregation function (i.e. sum) and a group-by. So your query would look something like:

```
select language.name , sum((country.population * (language.percentage / 100)))
from language, country
group by language.name
order by name
```